# R string of fixed file gets only top record

Tags: r

I've loaded flat fixed width file into R, and then I need to produce some calculations on all lines.
But after applying `substr`  I got only single value taken from first row. Probably I'm missins something about my R variable sructure.  For reproducing I'm pasting context of my file, probably this part is also important how I read it, I afraid that recreating it inside the R will be not valid.

```
----------------------- this is context of my  test.txt
REC1 00000 127 
REC2 00000 158
REC3 00000 169
.

#and this my code
> p1 <- read.fwf( file="test.txt",width = c(14)) ###, format.full=c(14))
> head(p1 )
              V1
1 REC1 00000 127
2 REC2 00000 158
3 REC3 00000 169

> p2 <- as.data.frame(p1)
> str(p2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "REC1 00000 127" "REC2 00000 158" "REC3 00000 169"
sum(as.numeric(substr(p2, start = 15, stop = 16)))
##  [1] 12
```

> 

Comment: Substring works for a single string. Given that your p2 contains multiple strings of V2, it is reasonable that substring return you the value for the first element, i.e. the 15th and 16th character of "REC1 00000 127" which is "12".

Comment: 1) You don't need `as.data.frame` the return value of `read.fwf` already is one; 2) try `p2$V1` in `substr`.

Comment: If your txt file has one record per line then use `read.table(test.txt, sep = " ")` to read it in.

Comment: Thanks Adam and Rui !!!!!!! You saved my weekend.